# Why queries are running slower after converting the column from VARCHAR to DATETIME

Tags: mysql, datetime, indexing

I have a table with a column `record_datetime` which used to be a `VARCHAR`. I tried changing it to DateTime, as it should be, but the queries are taking lot more time [almost 10 times more]. Why would it slow down??

This table has close to 100 million rows and `record_datetime` is an index. My test query I tried to run is

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE `record_datetime` >= '2012-06-12 00:00:00' 
  AND `Source` = 6 
ORDER BY `redord_datetime`
```

`Source` is part of the `PRIMARY KEY`, which is combination of user_id,record_datetime and Source. And `record_datetime` is the only index.

Here is what EXPLAIN said:

```
   id   select_type table type possible_keys key  key_len ref   rows      Extra
    1   SIMPLE       t0    ALL    Date       NULL   NULL  NULL 77489783  Using where
```

Thanks

Comment: Show the `EXPLAIN`. The index that is required for this query is a composite `source + record_datetime` (in this particular order) PS: how many rows is selected with this query?

Comment: I didn't use LIMIT, if thats what you are asking

Comment: Can you post `show create table table1`?

Comment: Did you have an index on the old column which is no longer there?

Comment: @usp: neither of my questions was related to `LIMIT`. Still: how many rows are returned? 77M? If so - nothing will help you. 77M is 77% of 100M and mysql would never use indexes for it. I don't even mention it takes *some time* to read (and transfer back) 77M rows

Comment: @zerkms but its way faster when I am using the VARCHAR. Thats what I didn't understand!!

Comment: @usp I don't have a proper explanation, but this query is terrible anyway - it cannot be optimized

Comment: @zerkms actually the query should return around 2000 rows as my datetime value in the where clause is  yesterday

Comment: @usp: then follow my (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097811/why-queries-are-running-slower-after-converting-the-column-from-varchar-to-datet?noredirect=1#comment24734172_17097811) and Bill Karwin's advice about creating a new index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EXPLAIN shows the `type` column is "ALL" which means it's scanning the whole table, it's not using the primary key or any index to help.

It can't use the primary key index, because you're only searching on the 2nd and 3rd columns.  To get an index to help, you need your search columns to be the leftmost columns of the index.  You also should have the columns involved in *equality* comparison listed to the left of columns involved in *range* comparison.

So you need an index on (Source, Record_datetime).

MySQL also tries to be intelligent about avoiding using an index when the index isn't helpful enough and would just be needless overhead.  For example, if the specific date range you're searching for (>= '2012-06-12') is the majority of the table, it just falls back to an "ALL" (table-scan).  If your other condition Source=6 significantly reduces the matched rows, it would help a lot to list that column *before* the Record_datetime column in the index.

Comment: He selects 77%+ of the table, nothing will help here :-)

Comment: @zerkms, you can't infer that from the `rows` column.  That's the estimated number of rows *examined*, not the number of rows returned.

Comment: I always thought that it's close to the returned number for the full table scan (since it scans the full table anyway)

Comment: @zerkms, the WHERE clause can eliminate a lot of the examined rows.  In fact in this case, it clearly does, given that usp expects only ~2000 rows returned.

Comment: @zerkms, the OP said "close to 100 million" and may be overestimating that as well.  Also, the number reported by EXPLAIN is only a rough estimate, and it can be inaccurate by a significant amount.

Comment: @BillKarwin you are right. having index on (Source, Record_datetime) made my query faster.

Comment: @usp, how does the EXPLAIN look now that you have the index?  What does `rows` show now?